# Secured controller returns 403 one one action but not on another in Grails app

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security, url-mapping

I have a controller in my app as follows:

```
@Secured(UserRoles.ROLE_USER)
class ProjectController implements BaseController, SpringSecurityAware {

    ProjectService projectService

    def create(ProjectCommand command) {
        ...
    }

    def update(ProjectCommand command) {
        Long projectId = params.id
        ...
    }
}
```

And it mapped as follows:

```
post "/v1/api/project" (controller: "project", action: "create")

put "/v1/api/project/$id" {
   controller = "project"
   action = "update"
   constraints {
       id(matches:/\\\d+/)
   }
}
```

I am using spring security rest with a custom token storage. The authentication mechanism works properly, as it's been tested and run for a while already.

When I am sending the post request to create the project, everything works fine. 
However, if I am trying to update the project I am getting 403 without even getting into the action method.

My request looks like this:

```
PUT /v1/api/project/12 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1qTTFPRGxETjBWR1FUQXlOa00wUkRoR056TkZSRGs1TlRFME1VVXlRa0ZDT0VFelJUazBRdyJ9....0qS2PUw8PQ
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=61F4874A906D706062C0209CEBF2AC3E
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.1.7 (Macintosh; OS X/10.13.5) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 77

title=Project+Update&background=Background&problemStatement=Problem+Statement
```

Notes:

1. `UserRoles.ROLE_USER` is a simple string
2. If I am debugging the request, the resolved user does have the expected authorities

What am I missing?
I suspect that there is something wrong with UrlMapping

**UPDATE**
Here is the debug log... It does not make much sense to me. It seems like it authenticated properly, but at the very end, the role was not allowed, even though it was the correct role.

```
2018-07-03 01:14:59.665 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/v1/api/project/12'; against '/v1/login'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.665 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/v1/api/project/12'; against '/v1/api/**'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.667 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /v1/api/project/12 at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityRequestHolderFilter'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.674 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /v1/api/project/12 at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.675 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/v1/api/project/12'; against '/logoff'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.675 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /v1/api/project/12 at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestAuthenticationFilter'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.675 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter      : Actual URI is /v1/api/project/12; endpoint URL is /api/login
2018-07-03 01:14:59.675 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /v1/api/project/12 at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.681 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /v1/api/project/12 at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestTokenValidationFilter'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.690 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.r.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader   : Looking for bearer token in Authorization header, query string or Form-Encoded body parameter
2018-07-03 01:14:59.690 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.r.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader   : Found bearer token in Authorization header
2018-07-03 01:14:59.690 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.r.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader   : Token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1qTTFPRGxETjBWR1FUQXlOa00wUkRoR056TkZSRGs1TlRFME1VVXlRa0ZDT0VFelJUazBRdyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNjY0NzgyMTY3NjY0Mzk5ODE2MCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcml6LWRldi5hdXRoMC5jb20vdXNlcmluZm8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTMwNjA1NjU5LCJleHAiOjE1MzA2MTI4NTksImF6cCI6ImtXcnJTT2Nsam1xM3dHTDB1SXR6ZVZ0ZjBMdzdidnlMIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.Oybu4Y4JKhWxuBBWST4f7bqge6AXxvx6wREkhU5OfA8WiR5vJ9Jd8NwjbsdfBss8A4ECjmsDTJb7yCT7nWlr0BAdimhcM6-hU_RtOEl8u_zxPnJrT4I58m_j2eWjoyGCa2snwnBwX1F49ls75bBeH_SEgd4pFanptfUCI2_UluqmvBnSuq_v5bGcB87k0OCcfXR_sZs8Cj_Llt-pgf8yYYisX8EBwfyTm6DeHcSgYPQedGY5zORuZ5T6jlpx3xJwc8J3MrXXUyTRvvZPy7mzyyd12Yfjmh2qrFZ_yFY9yaJVAMtZheLAT0GiamrRtLwL6AcQ-zdJqZJ6ik_4nLPw8g
2018-07-03 01:14:59.699 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter     : Token found: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1qTTFPRGxETjBWR1FUQXlOa00wUkRoR056TkZSRGs1TlRFME1VVXlRa0ZDT0VFelJUazBRdyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNjY0NzgyMTY3NjY0Mzk5ODE2MCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcml6LWRldi5hdXRoMC5jb20vdXNlcmluZm8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTMwNjA1NjU5LCJleHAiOjE1MzA2MTI4NTksImF6cCI6ImtXcnJTT2Nsam1xM3dHTDB1SXR6ZVZ0ZjBMdzdidnlMIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.Oybu4Y4JKhWxuBBWST4f7bqge6AXxvx6wREkhU5OfA8WiR5vJ9Jd8NwjbsdfBss8A4ECjmsDTJb7yCT7nWlr0BAdimhcM6-hU_RtOEl8u_zxPnJrT4I58m_j2eWjoyGCa2snwnBwX1F49ls75bBeH_SEgd4pFanptfUCI2_UluqmvBnSuq_v5bGcB87k0OCcfXR_sZs8Cj_Llt-pgf8yYYisX8EBwfyTm6DeHcSgYPQedGY5zORuZ5T6jlpx3xJwc8J3MrXXUyTRvvZPy7mzyyd12Yfjmh2qrFZ_yFY9yaJVAMtZheLAT0GiamrRtLwL6AcQ-zdJqZJ6ik_4nLPw8g
2018-07-03 01:14:59.699 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter     : Trying to authenticate the token
2018-07-03 01:14:59.699 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestAuthenticationProvider    : Use JWT: false
2018-07-03 01:14:59.699 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestAuthenticationProvider    : Trying to validate token eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1qTTFPRGxETjBWR1FUQXlOa00wUkRoR056TkZSRGs1TlRFME1VVXlRa0ZDT0VFelJUazBRdyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNjY0NzgyMTY3NjY0Mzk5ODE2MCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcml6LWRldi5hdXRoMC5jb20vdXNlcmluZm8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTMwNjA1NjU5LCJleHAiOjE1MzA2MTI4NTksImF6cCI6ImtXcnJTT2Nsam1xM3dHTDB1SXR6ZVZ0ZjBMdzdidnlMIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.Oybu4Y4JKhWxuBBWST4f7bqge6AXxvx6wREkhU5OfA8WiR5vJ9Jd8NwjbsdfBss8A4ECjmsDTJb7yCT7nWlr0BAdimhcM6-hU_RtOEl8u_zxPnJrT4I58m_j2eWjoyGCa2snwnBwX1F49ls75bBeH_SEgd4pFanptfUCI2_UluqmvBnSuq_v5bGcB87k0OCcfXR_sZs8Cj_Llt-pgf8yYYisX8EBwfyTm6DeHcSgYPQedGY5zORuZ5T6jlpx3xJwc8J3MrXXUyTRvvZPy7mzyyd12Yfjmh2qrFZ_yFY9yaJVAMtZheLAT0GiamrRtLwL6AcQ-zdJqZJ6ik_4nLPw8g
2018-07-03 01:14:59.873 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestAuthenticationProvider    : Authentication result: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1qTTFPRGxETjBWR1FUQXlOa00wUkRoR056TkZSRGs1TlRFME1VVXlRa0ZDT0VFelJUazBRdyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNjY0NzgyMTY3NjY0Mzk5ODE2MCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcml6LWRldi5hdXRoMC5jb20vdXNlcmluZm8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTMwNjA1NjU5LCJleHAiOjE1MzA2MTI4NTksImF6cCI6ImtXcnJTT2Nsam1xM3dHTDB1SXR6ZVZ0ZjBMdzdidnlMIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.Oybu4Y4JKhWxuBBWST4f7bqge6AXxvx6wREkhU5OfA8WiR5vJ9Jd8NwjbsdfBss8A4ECjmsDTJb7yCT7nWlr0BAdimhcM6-hU_RtOEl8u_zxPnJrT4I58m_j2eWjoyGCa2snwnBwX1F49ls75bBeH_SEgd4pFanptfUCI2_UluqmvBnSuq_v5bGcB87k0OCcfXR_sZs8Cj_Llt-pgf8yYYisX8EBwfyTm6DeHcSgYPQedGY5zORuZ5T6jlpx3xJwc8J3MrXXUyTRvvZPy7mzyyd12Yfjmh2qrFZ_yFY9yaJVAMtZheLAT0GiamrRtLwL6AcQ-zdJqZJ6ik_4nLPw8g, accessTokenJwt:null, expiration:null, refreshToken:null, refreshTokenJwt:null, principal:grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@2dba1e: Username: alex; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@4430b82e: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@2dba1e: Username: alex; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER)
2018-07-03 01:14:59.873 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter     : Token authenticated. Storing the authentication result in the security context
2018-07-03 01:14:59.873 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter     : Authentication result: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1qTTFPRGxETjBWR1FUQXlOa00wUkRoR056TkZSRGs1TlRFME1VVXlRa0ZDT0VFelJUazBRdyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNjY0NzgyMTY3NjY0Mzk5ODE2MCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcml6LWRldi5hdXRoMC5jb20vdXNlcmluZm8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTMwNjA1NjU5LCJleHAiOjE1MzA2MTI4NTksImF6cCI6ImtXcnJTT2Nsam1xM3dHTDB1SXR6ZVZ0ZjBMdzdidnlMIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.Oybu4Y4JKhWxuBBWST4f7bqge6AXxvx6wREkhU5OfA8WiR5vJ9Jd8NwjbsdfBss8A4ECjmsDTJb7yCT7nWlr0BAdimhcM6-hU_RtOEl8u_zxPnJrT4I58m_j2eWjoyGCa2snwnBwX1F49ls75bBeH_SEgd4pFanptfUCI2_UluqmvBnSuq_v5bGcB87k0OCcfXR_sZs8Cj_Llt-pgf8yYYisX8EBwfyTm6DeHcSgYPQedGY5zORuZ5T6jlpx3xJwc8J3MrXXUyTRvvZPy7mzyyd12Yfjmh2qrFZ_yFY9yaJVAMtZheLAT0GiamrRtLwL6AcQ-zdJqZJ6ik_4nLPw8g, accessTokenJwt:null, expiration:null, refreshToken:null, refreshTokenJwt:null, principal:grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@2dba1e: Username: alex; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@4430b82e: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@2dba1e: Username: alex; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER)
2018-07-03 01:14:59.873 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.p.s.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter     : Continuing the filter chain
2018-07-03 01:14:59.878 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /v1/api/project/12 at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.878 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /v1/api/project/12 at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-07-03 01:14:59.977 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /v1/api/project/12; Attributes: [_DENY_]
2018-07-03 01:14:59.978 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken(accessToken:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1qTTFPRGxETjBWR1FUQXlOa00wUkRoR056TkZSRGs1TlRFME1VVXlRa0ZDT0VFelJUazBRdyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNjY0NzgyMTY3NjY0Mzk5ODE2MCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL3ByaXotZGV2LmF1dGgwLmNvbS9hcGkvdjIvIiwiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcml6LWRldi5hdXRoMC5jb20vdXNlcmluZm8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTMwNjA1NjU5LCJleHAiOjE1MzA2MTI4NTksImF6cCI6ImtXcnJTT2Nsam1xM3dHTDB1SXR6ZVZ0ZjBMdzdidnlMIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.Oybu4Y4JKhWxuBBWST4f7bqge6AXxvx6wREkhU5OfA8WiR5vJ9Jd8NwjbsdfBss8A4ECjmsDTJb7yCT7nWlr0BAdimhcM6-hU_RtOEl8u_zxPnJrT4I58m_j2eWjoyGCa2snwnBwX1F49ls75bBeH_SEgd4pFanptfUCI2_UluqmvBnSuq_v5bGcB87k0OCcfXR_sZs8Cj_Llt-pgf8yYYisX8EBwfyTm6DeHcSgYPQedGY5zORuZ5T6jlpx3xJwc8J3MrXXUyTRvvZPy7mzyyd12Yfjmh2qrFZ_yFY9yaJVAMtZheLAT0GiamrRtLwL6AcQ-zdJqZJ6ik_4nLPw8g, accessTokenJwt:null, expiration:null, refreshToken:null, refreshTokenJwt:null, principal:grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@2dba1e: Username: alex; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER, super:grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.AccessToken@4430b82e: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@2dba1e: Username: alex; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER)
2018-07-03 01:14:59.979 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_USER] one can reach [ROLE_USER] in zero or more steps.
2018-07-03 01:14:59.997 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AbstractAccessDecisionManager.checkAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(AbstractAccessDecisionManager.java:70)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.decide(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.groovy:50)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:121)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2018-07-03 01:15:00.005 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/v1/login'
2018-07-03 01:15:00.005 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/v1/api/**'
2018-07-03 01:15:00.005 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error has no matching filters
```

Comment: to debug what is going on with SpringSecuyrity add debug logging to your config, otherwise its guessing: https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#debugging Also, make sure you don't have any Filters that prevents request in your localhost environment. You could strip the UrlMapping for the update action piece by piece and repeat the request after every change to see what is the one that give you the 403

Comment: @TuomasValtonen I added the output of the log

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was not related to security at all.
The issue was with the UrlMapping.

The UrlMapping for the update was supposed to be:

```
put "/v1/api/project/$id" {
   controller = "project"
   action = "update"
   constraints {
       id(matches:/\d+/)
   }
}
```

The regex for constraints was wrong.

However, I still don't understand why 403 was returned and not 404.